# android : Save a value even if the app was closed

Tags: android, list, object

I'm working on a project and I need to save a List of object ( that i have created , say device.java ) and to be able to retrieve it even after restarting the application 
I was told to use SharedPreferences but it doesn't seem to work for non built-in objects.. 
Any idea what to do?
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android, data storage can be done in multiple ways

1. Shared Preferences - Save values in the form of key-value pair. Data is available even if the application is closed or the phone is turned off and on.
2. **SQLITE** - Sql database for android mobile application. Data persist forever. Data of type objects can be stored in tables and retried as and when needed.
3. Internal Storage - Store private data on the device memory.
4. External Storage - Store public data on the shared external storage.

Out of all this options, SQLITE suits your needs. Refer to this link.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: by external storage, do you mean on our(app owner's) server/database?

Answer (score 0):

There is a librbary called GSON its good for serializing objects to json that is simple string. Than you can save it to shared preferences on application close. And ofcorse deserilize them when you need.

```
device obj = new device ();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

This is how to wrire it in preferences:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("myList", "json").commit();
```

Link to the library:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/